# STM32F030 RTC wakeup from stop mode

Tags: stm32, low-power, rtc

I'm writing an app, that most of its time will spend in STOP or STANDBY mode (battery powered microsystem). I'd like the internal RTC to wakeup my STM32 every 5 minutes, enter the ISR, do its tasks in ISR (ADC measurement and send it over) and enter back the STOP mode.

My question is: how to do it nice and simple?

I tried with RTC alarm interrupt, but when I set 5 minutes in the alarm register, the interrupt run every 10 minutes (5 min, 15 min, 25 min and so on... - actually I had tested with 5 seconds). I tried to reset the time register in the ISR, but it works only sometimes.

Could you give me some advice what's the best way to do a periodic wakeup in [STM32F30](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00058181.pdf)?

Comment: Keep tinkering with the RTC.  Consider an alarm every 2.5 minutes...

Comment: Also think your idea is probably the right one - just not implemented correctly. Keep in mind that in stop/standby the CLK-sources can be slowed down to save power - which may explain why your 5min-alarm turns out to be 10min...

Comment: I solved my problem. It was the missing semicolon at the end of while, that was waiting while polling a flag inside ISR. The code works now. Thanks for your advices:)